# Installation failed

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install ubuntu permanently in my hard disk along side windows 7, but after the 4th step of the installation (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) the computer restarted without completing the process. I tried 2 times. Do someone know what is that problem or an easy step-by-step alternative?

My computer is a HP laptop (pavilion dm1) with 2 core AMD ALU and 3Mhz of RAM, etc.

---

I find relevant information in the installation guide:

If you currently have one hard disk with one partition (a common setup for desktop computers), and you want to multi-boot the native operating system and Ubuntu, you will need to:

```
Back up everything on the computer.

Boot from the native operating system installer media such as CD-ROM or tapes.

Use the native partitioning tools to create native system partition(s). Leave either a place holder partition or free space for Ubuntu.

Install the native operating system on its new partition.

Boot back into the native system to verify everything's OK, and to download the Ubuntu installer boot files.

Boot the Ubuntu installer to continue installing Ubuntu.
```

So I will try to find information on how to do that if some knows where I can find a step-by-step guide I will be grateful (or any other suggestion)

Comment: unclear . provide more information

Comment: what information you think might be helpful?

Comment: screen shots and any error messages

Comment: there is not error messages i followed exactly the instruction in the page of the link above and on the 4th step the computer restart instead of taking me to the 5th step. the 4th step ask me if I want to install ubuntu inside windows 7 or to erase all the files inside my hard drive. Please forgive me if I'm not clear enough (Is the first time I install ubuntu)

Comment: use "something else" :) make partition and install . grub will detect windows.
you may try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing from a Live system?

Choose "Try Ubuntu" at the very beginning, then run the installer from the live system.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

At the very least you will get an error message you can report back here.

Comment: yes I already try ubuntu And want to install it permanently in my hard drive because when I run ubuntu from USB it is rather slow. Thanks for your help

Comment: I find some relevant information in the installation guide I paste it in main section of this post...thanks again.